# Google chart not displayed, from json file and ajax call.

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Json file I'm sending from controller to google chart view not getting displayed. I think its in the format of the json file. I'm also displaying the returned json string to a `<code></code>` block.

If I manually hard code the returned json string, the chart displays. The controller method, MakeStringDataTable(), returns a stringbuilder object. Also at the end of this post is the fiddler values.

client side code

```
  function GetChartData() {
     alert("GetChartData()");

     var url = '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Graphing")';
     var stockitems = $('#SelectedStockItemID'); // cache it
     var stockGroups = $('#SelectedStockGroupID'); // cache it
     var customers = $('#SelectedCustomerID'); // cache it
     // public JsonResult GetChartData(int ? customerID, int ? stockItemID, int ? stockGroupID)

     $.getJSON(url, { StockGroupID: stockGroups.val(), stockItemID: stockitems.val(), customerID: customers.val() },
        function (response) {

           alert("call back from getJSON()");
           $("#codeDisplay").text(response);
           // Load google charts
           var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response, false);
           //var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Month", "2015", "2016"], ["Jan", 0, 14264.00], ["Feb", 0, 9465.70], ["Mar", 0, 1069.50], ["Apr", 0, 17061.00], ["May", 0, 14656.60], ["Dec", 6858.65, 0]], false);
           alert("after arraytoDataTable");

           // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
           var options = { 'width': 1000, 'height': 600 };

           // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
           var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('SalesChart'));
           chart.draw(data, options);

     });
```

code behind

```
  public JsonResult GetChartData(int? customerID, int? stockItemID, int? stockGroupID)
  {
     GraphSalesByYearMonth gsbym = DoGraphing(customerID, stockItemID, stockGroupID);

     string s = gsbym.MakeStringDataTable().ToString();
     //return Json(gsbym.MakeStringDataTable(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     //string xx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gsbym.MakeStringDataTable());
     return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

json data

```
"[[\"Month\",\"2015\",\"2016\"],[\"Jan\",0,5377.15],[\"Feb\",0,10770.50],[\"Mar\",0,17610.00],[\"Apr\",0,17529.90],[\"May\",0,6663.80],[\"Oct\",514.00,0],[\"Dec\",1506.00,0]]"
```

Comment: Please give your question an appropriate title, not just a list of tags.

Comment: Try to debug the code, in the client code, what is the response? `alert(JSON.stringify(response))`. Does the response has the same structure as your manually entered values?

Comment: The manually entered values is the response from the ajax call. Just copied and pasted from a "code""/code" tag. There is a difference, in the fidler response the string is enclosed with an opening and closing double quote.

Comment: Fixed the problem. It was the return statement of the controller. Changed it from return json(s) to  return javaScript(s); Also changed the controller return type from JsonResult to ActionResult.